# Storing Non-Visible (But Required) Information in a FlowDocument

Tags: xaml, xslt, flowdocument

I am trying to write a two-way `XHTML` to `FlowDocument` (FD) XSLT transformation, and I'm running into a recurring issue - there are things you can do in HTML that don't make sense (at least in this early version) in a FD.  For example, XHTML has the notion of an `accesskey` attribute, but there is no corresponding FD XAML element.

Even though the FD has no use for it, I need a way to store this information in the XAML of the FD so I can retrieve it later.  Something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match=@accesskey>
    <InvisibleElement name="accesskey" value="." />
</xsl:template>
```

...but to my knowledge, there is **no** FD element that doesn't have a corresponding display.  I suppose I could use an empty `<Span />` or `<Run />`, but that could lead to issues if someone edits the document and inadvertently adds content where I don't expect it.

Another option might be:

```
<xsl:template match="@accesskey">
   <InlineUIContainer Tag="accesskey">
      <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" Tag="{.}" />
   </InlineUIContainer>
</xsl:template>
```

Since it wouldn't be visible, it'd be uneditable.

Suggestions?

Comment: Tried `<FlowDocument.Resources><someXmlns:SomeType x:Key="SomeKey" SomeValue="something" /><FlowDocument.Resources />`?

Comment: @Will these elements/attributes will occur throughout the HTML document - if I *do* store them in a Resource, how will I know where to put them when I transform the FlowDocument back to HTML?

Comment: Refer to other elements by their x:Names?  Or create custom attributes using attached properties?

Comment: Since FlowDocuments are XAML, which is XML, I would assume you can simply store them in any element that is not in the FD or XAML namespace. Add an element in namespace `http://extra` (name doesn't matter, as long as MS doesn't know it), and you can roundtrip your transformation.